# Xcode iPhone simulator acting funky

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

I have just begun an iPhone app tutorial. What shows up in my storyboard is starkly different to what shows up in the iPhone simulator:

[image: This shows the "Hello World" message as being on the left]

[image: This shows it on the right]

One shows the "Hello World" message as being on the left

The other shows it on the right

The window is maxed out, so it's not just a viewing error. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

I think you should start learning [Auto Layout](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/Introduction/Introduction.html) and after that add some constrains to your label

Comment: @NimrodSadeh What kind of constrains have you added ?

Answer (score 1):

[image]What you want to do is got to **View > Utilities > Show the attributes inspector** Under ***Simulated metrics*** change the ***Size*** (which is `Inferred` by default) depending from what you want..

Note: Make sure you have selected your view controller, see the image...

for dynamic approach..

Make use of your autolayout and set constraints.. 
at the bottom right of the storyboard click `Align` and set your prefered `Alignment Constraints`..

I'm out here, Cheers to you sir..

Comment: Without constrains even size does not matter

Comment: Yes, but you can properly align your views if can see the actual rect of your view. my answer is not dynamic but i'm just answering what is ask..

Comment: @zellb There.. i edited my answer for your satisfaction, 

i dont get it why you need to down vote me, what he stated is:
** What shows up in my storyboard is starkly different to what shows up in the iPhone simulator**

So i think what he needed is to design with the actual size he wanted to.. tsk.

Comment: Nothing happens when I click "Show the attribute inspector"

Comment: @NimrodSadeh *Simulated metrics* change the *Size* .. >.<

Comment: @0yeji it's not there

Comment: @NimrodSadeh Make sure you selected the View Controller/ the icon (tiny yellow circle)

Answer (score 0):

The location of the label is the same if you don`t use autolayout correctly.

Select the label and add the constraint, you can play with these and auto adjust the frame.

[image]

Comment: This did not work. I also don't get why it has to be so complicated - in the video tutorial he just placed the label, clicked run and voila it was there at the right place.

Comment: Clean your application and delete from the simulator, i don't have this situation.

Answer (score 0):

Set your layout to compact width | regular height

[image]

Comment: Did not change result

Comment: @NimrodSadeh you need to reposition you text and apply suggested constraints to it

Comment: Select your Label go to Editor > Resolve Auto layout Issues and Reset to Suggested Constraints

Answer (score 0):

Ok two things i want to tell you here !!
What you see in storyboard is not what gets rendered in simulator !, the storyboard is just for your visual assistance , but if this is puzzling you , do one thing go to storyboard ->identityInspector(top right side panel) select 4th tab -> simulated Metrics ->size (click on it and find the one simulator on which you are running).

2nd thing -> 
if you want  the frames be adjusted as per changing resolution ,you better make sure to use autolayout and set appropriate constraint .

Comment: Well it's not a very useful visual assistance if it does not show what actually happens... Also that view does not have simulated metrics on my version of Xcode

Comment: Auto layout also shows the constraints as being vertically symmetrical, shouldn't it simulate that way too?

Comment: Which version of xcode are you using?  about autolayout  select that label and , press control, drag to the left , and set left margin to superview , 
same you do for setting vertical constraint    ,

Dont set  constraint for left side and bottom side , try doing this let me know the result